# Phd plagiarism detection question

Tags: phd

whats the maximum percent of similarity acceptable at phd dissertation  in the most of univesities ?

I have not any plagiarism but iam wondering about similarity percent that most universities or journal limited to accept the work
Regards

Comment: Maybe just don't plagiarize and worry less about software?

Comment: Politicians in my country have decided that 75% is still acceptable.

Comment: 75% very high percent that mean most of dissertation copy paste

Comment: [Depends](http://www.newyorker.com/news/news-desk/russias-dissertation-fraud-muckrakers) on the country...

Answer (score 2):

There is no such thing as maximum percent of similarity between texts to diagnose plagiarism. Although some softwares consider it to be definitely a case of plagiarism when a sentence has 7 or more consecutive words identical to those present in a different excerpt, plagiarism can happen AND be detected even if you could change every word of the text. If you reproduce a finding or an idea which is not originally yours without properly referencing the author, it is plagiarism, the only difference is if the unethical behavior is obvious (crtl C ctrl V of some other text) or an elaborate one. I've seen a case of plagiarism where the accused PhD candidate switched results from a previous research about soccer and put it in his/her thesis as if was his/her results. The case was not obvious at first sight and it took the university about a year to analyze and determine that it was actually plagiarism...
Science is forever and it is being watched by thousands around the globe, sooner or later plagiarists will be caught so it is just not worth it to ruin your career.